# Почему на компе не работает slider бустрапа на WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, bootstrap, slider

- Стлокнулся с проблемой. Добавил на хостинг roflanhost.beget.tech шаблон верстки на WP
  Подключил стили, скрипты

```js
<?php 
// правильный способ подключить стили и скрипты 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cafeesa_add_scripts' );
function cafeesa_add_scripts() {
  // подключаем файл стилей темы
  wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.min.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'style-main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'responsive', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/responsive.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
// подключаем js файл темы
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-core' );
wp_register_script( 'jquery-core', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );

}

add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
```

- И slider не срабатывает, когда я зашел с телефона то там все работает. (у одного знакомого с компа все окей, у другого типо тоже не работает)
  В инспекторе чекал, когда стрелку жмешь то типо классы меняются. Но ничего не двигется.

Answer (score 0):

Решено, изменил в файле bootstrap.css  = c none на 1s
@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
.carousel-item {
transition: 1s;
}
}

- странно что на некоторых устройствах оно работало.